# C# display a string into a table

Tags: c#, string

i'm learning programming in C# and would like to know if it is possible to output the value of a string that is 12 letters long into a table with 12 columns, each column will have one label which one letter of the string will be displayed in

Comment: What kind of table? It's doable, definitely, just curious.

Comment: well its the tableLayoutPanel container in windows form, each column has a label and the string will put one letter in each

Comment: Welcome on SO, as you obviously don't know, this community is all about problem solving. We are not there to provide you with any code, unless you tried something. Please read the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting your next question ;)

You should also have a look there: http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just iterate the characters and do whatever you want. And it would go a little something like this:

```
        // create an instance of your table, whatever it may be.
        // create an instance of a row
        // add row to your table
        var line = "hello world";
        foreach (var letter in line)
        {
            // create an instance of a column
            // add column to your row
            // add label to your column
            // set text property of lable = letter
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the String.Format method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx